# Can't click button when soft-keyboard is visible

Tags: javascript, html, ios, keyboard, telerik

When an text input element has focus (and the soft keyboard is visible), I can't click the submit button (which is clearly visible) directly. I have to first dismiss the keyboard (by clicking elsewhere or on "Done" on the keyboard), and then click the submit button.

This is confusing behaviour. I have considered removing the log-in button altogether when the keyboard is visible, but that would be too confusing (for users wouldn't know that they could click "Go", or will be annoyed that the login button keeps disappearing).

This only happens on iOS (not sure if its restricted to iOS 7, but suspect it might be), and I'm using Telirik AppBuilder for my app.

Comment: Resign the keyboard (using [textFied resignFirstResponder];) for that particular field within the submit button action.so, when clicking the submit button the keyboard will be automatically dismissed.

Comment: @gunas As mentioned in the OP, I'm not writing native code. This needs to be done via the framework mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

```
function isTextInput(node) {
return ['INPUT', 'TEXTAREA'].indexOf(node.nodeName) !== -1;
}
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    if (!isTextInput(e.target) && isTextInput(document.activeElement)) {
        document.activeElement.blur();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I shall try it out today, and accept it if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Because I was using `<button>` tag the soft keyboard popped up when not required. I have now changed all for `<table>` (inside a `<td>` tag, but could be a `<div>` ) with an `<img>` tag inside for the icons. To make the table look more like a button there is a CSS class for colours/borders. A submit area is right at the top (too).

The page can be inspected at http://ask.stroudvoices.co.uk/

It would seem that Android (assume iPad etc also) treat buttons as another kind of `<input>`, whereas `<table>` is regarded as `<body>`.

Sometimes there is a simple answer, from old technology!

Answer (score 0):

I meet a similar problem.What my need is when I tap the submit button and I want to keep the soft-keyboard visible.
Here is my solution.

```
submit.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I give the submit button a mousedown event, and prevent the default event. it's work on most mobile phones.but in some system found ios 12.1.2 is not available.it's just like the question's owner says, i need to tap twice, one to hide the keyboard, second to reach the submit button.
This confused me and I can't solve it.