# Can't touch a visible button while the soft-keyboard is active

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm doing a simple chat-client and wish to be able to write a message in my editText and without closing the soft-keyboard click the "Send"-button which is right next to the editText and is fully visible. This cannot be done currently.

**MY XML**

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/connect"
            android:id="@+id/connectButton"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top"
            android:onClick="ConnectButtonClicked"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:onClick="SendButtonClicked"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="228dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
            android:inputType="textLongMessage" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/usernameEditText"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="391dp"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/chatTextView"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:maxLines="100"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**RELEVANT CLASS CODE**

```
public class ChatClientMainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    Socket socket;
    private ServerListener serverListener;
    private Thread listenerThread;
    public Handler messageHandler;
    private TextView chatTextView;
    private EditText usernameEditText;
    private EditText messageEditText;
    private Button sendButton;
    private Button connectButton;
    private int PORT = 2001;
    private String hostAddress = "192.168.1.3";


    private static class HandlerExtension extends Handler
    {
        private final WeakReference<ChatClientMainActivity> currentActivity;

        public HandlerExtension(ChatClientMainActivity activity){
            currentActivity = new WeakReference<ChatClientMainActivity>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            ChatClientMainActivity UIActivity = currentActivity.get();

            if (msg != null)
            {
                Bundle tempBundle = msg.getData();
                UIActivity.PrintMessage(tempBundle.getString("chatMessage"));
            }
            else
            {
                // ALERT MESSAGE
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_client_main);

        messageHandler = new HandlerExtension(this);

        chatTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatTextView);
        chatTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        connectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectButton);
        sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        usernameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameEditText);
        messageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
        messageEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
                if(keyCode == event.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                    SendButtonClicked(v);
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(messageEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        //InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        //imm.SoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
    }

    public void SendButtonClicked(View view)
    {
        String message = messageEditText.getText().toString();
        if (!message.equals(""))
            ServerListener.SendMessage(message);
        messageEditText.setText("");
    }

    public void ConnectButtonClicked(View view)
    {
        if (connectButton.getText().toString().equals("Connect"))
        {
            if (usernameEditText.getText().toString() != "")
            {
                if (usernameEditText.getText().length() <= 10)
                {
                    String username = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
                    listenerThread = new Thread(new ServerListener(this, "192.168.1.3", username, messageHandler));
                    listenerThread.start();

                    sendButton.setEnabled(true);
                    connectButton.setText("Disconnect");
                    usernameEditText.setEnabled(false);
                    PrintMessage("Welcome to the chat!");
                }
                else
                {
                    // "Username max length is 10 characters"
                    //
                    // Dialog dialog = new Dialog(null);
                    // TextView txt = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // "Enter a username!"
                // Dialog dialog = new Dialog(null);
            }
        }
        else if (connectButton.getText().toString() == "Disconnect")
        {
            QuitChat("Disconnect");
            sendButton.setEnabled(false);
            connectButton.setText("Connect");
            usernameEditText.setText("");
            usernameEditText.setEnabled(true);

            // listenerThread.a
        }
    }

    public void PrintMessage(String lineToPrint)
    {
        Time now = new Time();
        now.setToNow();
        String timeString = now.format("%H:%M ");
        final String line = timeString + ": " + lineToPrint + "\n";
        messageHandler.post(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                chatTextView.setText(chatTextView.getText() + line);
                chatTextView.invalidate();
            }
        });
    }

    public void QuitChat(String input) {

        ServerListener.SendMessage("LOGOUT");

        //Quit chat
    }
}
```

A link to my java- and xml-files as well as a screen-shot of the situation:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8dfbq6c2xjkoqi5/AAA726NdFj5EjoyLyE94ecPWa?dl=0

There is an equivalent question for iOS but without an applicable answer.
[Can't click button when soft-keyboard is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327080/cant-click-button-when-soft-keyboard-is-visible)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

**SOLVED**
The problem was caused by this line in my layout xml: 
"android:scrollbars="vertical"/>". 
I'm new to Android-programming so if anyone can explain why then that would be great and I will accept that as an answer!

Comment: Shouldn't happen, can we see your xml and any relevant java/android?

Comment: Added a link to my files above!

Comment: Have you checked to make sure your conditionals are set like you would expect?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by conditionals in this case, the button is enabled and there shouldn't be any intentional code to prevent this action.

Comment: I found the cause of my problem! In my layout xml the textView had a vertical scrollbar and by removing this line of code "android:scrollbars="vertical"/>" the problem went away!